# pass variable from gulp file to mocha test file

Tags: gulp, mocha.js, gulp-mocha

I am trying execute mocha test file through gulp using gulp-mocha. Such that I need variable to be passed(or pipe) to mocha test file which can be accessed in mocha test file. How can I achieve this one

Comment: Please show the code you are trying to affect in your test suite. There are quite a few ways to convey information from gulp to Mocha, and which one works best depends on the specifics of what you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

To use a test file,

```
  gulp.task('taskname', function (done) {
        gulp.src('test/testfile.js')
            .pipe(gulpmocha(),setTimeout(function() {
                done(null);
        }, 5000))
    });
```

To pass a variable, you may need to post your code and test

Comment: How does one get to make these down voters leave a comment as to why the downvote?